# SQL Parsing a String

Tags: sql, sql-server, substring, charindex

Can someone tell me where i am going wrong, i cant seem to extract the fourth word CCC, tried everything, do not want to put it into a table just return the substring in a select?

```sql
DECLARE  @ProductCode VARCHAR(256) 

SET @ProductCode = 'CCCC-DDDDDDD-AAA-CCC-BBBBB' 

SELECT LEFT(@ProductCode,CHARINDEX('-',@ProductCode) - 1) AS CHAR1, 

    SUBSTRING(@ProductCode,CHARINDEX('-',@ProductCode) + 1, 
                CHARINDEX('-',@ProductCode,CHARINDEX('-', @ProductCode) + 1) - (CHARINDEX('-',@ProductCode) + 1)) AS CHAR2, 
        
    SUBSTRING(@ProductCode,CHARINDEX('-',@ProductCode,CHARINDEX('-',@ProductCode) + 1) + 1, 
                DATALENGTH(@ProductCode) - CHARINDEX('-', @ProductCode,CHARINDEX('-',@ProductCode) + 1) - CHARINDEX('-',REVERSE(@ProductCode))) AS CHAR3, 

    SUBSTRING(@ProductCode,CHARINDEX('-',@ProductCode,CHARINDEX('-',@ProductCode), CHARINDEX('-',@ProductCode) + 1)) + 1, 
DATALENGTH(@ProductCode) - CHARINDEX('-', @ProductCode,CHARINDEX('-',@ProductCode), CHARINDEX('-',@ProductCode) + 1) - CHARINDEX('-',REVERSE(@ProductCode))) AS CHAR4,
       RIGHT(@ProductCode,CHARINDEX('-',REVERSE(@ProductCode)) - 1) AS LASTCHAR

GO
```

Many thanks

Comment: Do yourself a favor and find a string splitting function that provides ordinal position. At some point MS will improve the built-in function to do the same. Only took 17 years to add TRIM.

Comment: And using datalength is logically incorrect. If you ever need to do with with nvarchar strings, your code will not work.

Comment: Is the string you're trying to extract always in the same position?

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps it would be simpler as:

```
select s.value
from string_split(@productcode, '-') s
where @productcode like '%-%-%-' + s.value + '-%' and
      @productcode not like '%-%-%-%-' + s.value + '-%' and
```

Comment: STRING_SPLIT requires the compatibility level to be at least 130

Comment: @JohnJoseph . . . Or phrased another way, it has been available since the current release of 2016-06-01 -- about four and half years now.

Comment: So, assuming you're trying to be helpful and not snarky... if the OP has SQL Server 2014 or earlier, there will be no option to alter the compatibility to 130 or higher.

Answer (score 0):

> below is one approach to complete the task:

```
select substring(@productcode,charindex('-',@ProductCode,charindex('-',@ProductCode,charindex('-',@ProductCode,charindex('-',@ProductCode))+1)+1)+1,datalength(@productcode)-charindex('-',@ProductCode,charindex('-',@ProductCode,charindex('-',@ProductCode,charindex('-',@ProductCode,charindex('-',@ProductCode))+1)+1)+1)-2);
```

> You are getting confused by using multiple approach to extract the
> string. You don't need REVERSE FUNTION to get the ending of the string
> , you can just keep extracting the position of '-' using charindex
> function and subtract it from the total length of the string.

Answer (score 0):

```
--get 3rd and 4th words (the same way as for the 2nd word)

DECLARE  @ProductCode VARCHAR(256) 

SET @ProductCode = 'CC12CC-DDD34DD-A56A-C78C-BB910BB' 

SELECT LEFT(@ProductCode,CHARINDEX('-',@ProductCode) - 1) AS CHAR1, 

SUBSTRING(@ProductCode,CHARINDEX('-',@ProductCode) + 1, 
                CHARINDEX('-',@ProductCode,CHARINDEX('-', @ProductCode) + 1) - (CHARINDEX('-',@ProductCode) + 1)) AS CHAR2, 
        
SUBSTRING(
@ProductCode,
--.. from position of 2nd "-" plus one 
CHARINDEX('-',@ProductCode, CHARINDEX('-', @ProductCode) + 1) + 1,
--as many chars as there are between 2nd&3rd "-"
CHARINDEX('-', @ProductCode, CHARINDEX('-',@ProductCode, CHARINDEX('-', @ProductCode) + 1) + 1) -1 --3rd "-" minus 1
- --minus position 2nd "-"
CHARINDEX('-',@ProductCode, CHARINDEX('-', @ProductCode) + 1) --= chars between 2nd and 3rd "-"
) as xCHAR3,                 
                
SUBSTRING(
@ProductCode,
--.. from position of 3rd "-" plus one 
CHARINDEX('-', @ProductCode, CHARINDEX('-',@ProductCode, CHARINDEX('-', @ProductCode) + 1) + 1) + 1,
--get as many chars as there are between 3rd&4th "-"
CHARINDEX('-', @ProductCode, CHARINDEX('-', @ProductCode, CHARINDEX('-',@ProductCode, CHARINDEX('-', @ProductCode) + 1) + 1)+1) -1 --4th "-" minus 1
- --minus position 3rd "-"
CHARINDEX('-', @ProductCode, CHARINDEX('-',@ProductCode, CHARINDEX('-', @ProductCode) + 1) + 1) --= chars between 3rd and 4th "-"
) as xCHAR4, 

RIGHT(@ProductCode,CHARINDEX('-',REVERSE(@ProductCode)) - 1) AS LASTCHAR

GO

--... or ...
DECLARE  @ProductCode VARCHAR(256);

SET @ProductCode = 'CC12CC-DDD34DD-A56A-C78C-BB910BB'; 

select 
    p.value('comment()[1]', 'varchar(100)') as char1,
    p.value('comment()[2]', 'varchar(100)') as char2,
    p.value('comment()[3]', 'varchar(100)') as char3,
    p.value('comment()[4]', 'varchar(100)') as char4,
    p.value('comment()[5]', 'varchar(100)') as char5                
from
(
--splitting on '-', xml comment is rather safe
select cast('<!--'+replace(@ProductCode, '-', '--><!--')+'-->' as xml) p
) as t;
```

Answer (score 0):

This approach has the advantage of being readable but it's ugly...

```
DECLARE  @ProductCode VARCHAR(256) 

SET @ProductCode = 'CCCC-DDDDDDD-AAA-CCC-BBBBB' 

select @ProductCode = substring(@ProductCode,charindex('-',@ProductCode)+1,99)
select @ProductCode = substring(@ProductCode,charindex('-',@ProductCode)+1,99)
select @ProductCode = substring(@ProductCode,charindex('-',@ProductCode)+1,99)
select @ProductCode = left(@ProductCode,charindex('-',@ProductCode)-1)

select @ProductCode
```

Answer (score 0):

This approach has the advantage of being flexible in that you can change the Nth word sought...

```
declare @ProductCode varchar(256) 
declare @WordSought int = 4
declare @Cntr int = 0

set @ProductCode = 'CCCC-DDDDDDD-AAA-CCC-BBBBB' 

while @cntr < @WordSought - 1
begin
    select @ProductCode = substring(@ProductCode,charindex('-',@ProductCode)+1,99)
    set @cntr = @cntr + 1
end

select left(@ProductCode,charindex('-',@ProductCode + '-') - 1)
```